# Place beamer frame title into parallelogram at top left corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, frame-title, tikz-positioning

I am trying to place the title of each frame in a parallelogram that adjusts to the length of the title. I want the parallelogram to start at the same position of each frame, for example, at the top left with a small offset to the left and top borders. I have problems with the placement and long titles go over the edge. So far I've got this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=Green!10}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Yellow!20}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=DarkBlue}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \tikzstyle{every node}=[trapezium, minimum width=0cm, minimum height=0cm, 
  trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, fill=Gray!20]
  
  \node[inner xsep=2pt] at ($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-1cm)$){
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
  };  
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{This is a test title!}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Short}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `anchor` option to define at which site the node should be anchored:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=Green!10}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=Brown,bg=Yellow!20}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=DarkBlue}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}

\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \tikzset{every node/.style={trapezium, minimum width=0cm, minimum height=0cm, 
  trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, fill=Gray!20}}
  
  \node[inner xsep=2pt,anchor=west] at ($(current page.north west)+(0.2cm,-1cm)$){
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
  };  
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{This is a test title!}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Short}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]